# .NET Core with Xamarin UITest: FileInfo claims it is defined in mscorlib

Tags: c#, android, xamarin, .net-core, xamarin.uitest

I'm converting my Xamarin Android application to .NET Standard, part of which involves making the UITest project target .NET Core 1.1. When trying to access the interface `IApp`, I get the following compiler error:

`Reference to type 'FileInfo' claims it is defined in 'mscorlib', but it could not be found.`

I have a PackageTargetFallback in my csproj letting me install the .NET4.5 package, and the `Microsoft.NETCore.Portable.Compatibility` nuget package installed to the project. What's going on?

Comment: You cannot reference both .net 4.5 and .Net standard libraries, they are defining the same classes

Comment: This is fixed in all other cases by using the `Microsoft.NETCore.Portable.Compatibility` package. I don't think it's the issue.