# xamarin UITest not compatible with dotnet core?

Tags: c#, xamarin, xamarin.uitest

My apologies for this one small question but i'm checking out to convert the xamarin uitest project to dotnet core. But i'm facing difficulties. When I create a new xamarin uitest project it is automatically in 4.6 and I don't have the option to set it to core. When I create a dotnet core class lib and add the xamarin uitest nuget package it will warn me that it was restored with net framework 461.

> Package 'Xamarin.UITest 3.0.7' was restored using '.NETFramework,Version=v4.6.1,

I just can't believe that UITest is not compatible with dotnet core... So i anybody can tell me this is the case or can point me why it is warning me and how to solve it that would be great. Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

Yeah, I noticed the same today. I wanted to change my UITest project to .Net Core but got the same warnings as you:

[image]

also looks like there may be other issues based on this [question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/43481875/net-core-with-xamarin-uitest-fileinfo-claims-it-is-defined-in-mscorlib)

However, the prerelease version [Xamarin.UITest 3.0.8-dev1](https://www.nuget.org/packages/Xamarin.UITest/3.0.8-dev1) seems to not show any warnings even tho they target the same.

[image]

Comment: Are you able to get Xamarin.UITest v3.0.8-dev1 working in .NET Core? My .NET Core 3.1 project says Xamarin.UITest namespace not found when I use v3.0.8-dev1.

Comment: hmm the namespace isn't available, you are right, I had to revert my project to .net 4.6.1 guess this doesn't work with .Net Core. I Tried the fallback for the NuGets too.. still nothing. Sorry I guess this answer doesn't help much.